# Comparación valor cercano ; Código

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 tablas en **SQL Server**, la tabla *giroscopio* tengo que compararla con la tabla *gps_1*, pero solo agarrar un elemento de la tabla *giroscopio* por ejemplo el 07.34 y compararla con un cierto rango de la tabla *gps_1* por ejemplo desde el 23.00 hasta el 36.00 y que me retorne el valor mas cercano entre esa comparación.

En caso  de que no existiera no pasaría nada. Y así el siguiente 07.40 con los 10 siguientes de la tabla *gps_1* . Luego de obtener esos valores cercanos se listarían en **C#**.

Tengo problemas en la comparación más que todo. Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque el 07.34 se compara desde el 23.00 hasta el 36.00? y el resto de los valores de la tabla gps_1 porque no se usan ? quien define este rango?  porque en el ejemplo dices que no hay resultado, esperas el mas cercano no una coincidencia exacta

Comment: Te explico lo que quiero lograr a hacer es comparar 1 elemento de la tabla con cierta cantidad(20) de la otra tabla .  Una vez realizada la comparación si hay un valor cercano entre las dos tablas que se concatenen ; ejem: en la 1era tabla tengo 7.65 y en la otra tabla varios valores entre ellos un 7.70 y un 7.63 ; entonces el 7.65 y el 7.63 se unirian y de ahi yo los listaria en C# .  Y asi con el siguiente comparar el 2do valor con cierta cantidad(20) de la otra tabla y asi sucesivamente..En caso no se encontrara un cercano pasaria a comparar el 2do con cierta cantidad(20) de la otra tabla.

Comment: con solo una query en sql lo veo bastante complejo, ya que por lo que entiendo deberias paginar los datos de gps_1 en bloques de 20. Igual no me queda claro porque no puedes cruzar todos los datos en lugar de solo tomar 20, si en definitiva vas a buscar el primero mas cercano

Comment: Claro puedo cruzar todos contra todos y me voten los cercanos ; pero la idea es hacerlo 1 contra 20 y luego el siguiente contra los siguientes 20. Quiero el valor más cercano de lo que estoy comparando; no el primero más cercano.  Alguna idea?

Comment: Creo que tengo las mismas dudas que leandro. No entiendo muy bien porque lo quieres hacer asi, podrias parafrasear de nuevo la pregunta quiza la podramos entender mejor de otra forma

Comment: :´v Comparar 1 elemento de tabla giroscopio con 20 de la gps1 ; si hay un valor cercano de esa comparación lo listaria en C#, y asi seguir comparando el 2 elemento de tabla giroscopio con los 20 siguientes de gps1, en caso de no ver un valor cercano en la comparacion seguir.  Exactamente problemas con el código como realizarlo puede ser cualquier lenguaje ; incluso sin esa base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien, este código te puede servir para encontrar el valor mas cercano entre ambas tablas

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(GIRO.valor3, 7, 5) AS valor3
             , SUBSTRING(GPS.valor2, 19, 5) AS valor2
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(CONVERT(FLOAT, SUBSTRING(GIRO.valor3, 7, 5)) - CONVERT(FLOAT, SUBSTRING(GPS.valor2, 19, 5))) AS orden
        FROM   giroscopio              GIRO
             , practica.dbo.gps_1      GPS
        ) D
WHERE   orden = 1
```

Por favor, dime si no comprendí bien la información que necesitas para ajustar la respuesta.

Saludos